# How to capture the save ribbon event for custom web part?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have two webparts on a Project Details Page, webpart #1 is a default form webpart, webpart#2 is a custom webpart with custom form.

Now when I click on "Save" in ribbon it fires the save event for Web Part 1.

My question: Is there a way to capture the save ribbon event, so I can trigger the save event of my custom web part ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can specify the `OnSaveHandler` at runtime as follows,

```
SPContext.Current.FormContext.OnSaveHandler = btnSave_Click;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to achieve this using javascript. You need to add your custom script block with function PreSaveAction.
Something like this:

```
<script>
function PreSaveAction(){
//Do your stuff
}
<script>
```

Please refer to [this](http://workflowssimplified.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/sharepoint-2010-validation-using-javascript/) post.